# PHPMailer - Repeating variables

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a HTML form that is being processed by a php page. I have had it working exactly as I need using **mail()** but am running into issues with the email part. Sending an email out is very inconsistent which is not acceptable. I understand that mail() only takes care of a small part of the process and the mail servers take care of the heavy lifting.

I am trying out [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example) as an alternative. I have it up and running and am able to get mail to go out but some of the functionality is not there.

In my form you can add multiple 'projects' to a single submission. The php is supposed to loop over those projects and create a section for each in the email. Again, this is working with mail() but doesn't always send.

The code I am trying to implement is below. It will send an email but will not loop over the form fields if there are more than one. It will only see the last one entered.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$today = date("F j - Y - g:i a");

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                       // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.example.com';      // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mail@example.com';  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';          // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';             // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'mail@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'From name';
$mail->addAddress('mail@example.com', 'personName');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('mail@anotherexample.com');          // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('mail@example.com', 'replyTO');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 500;                               // Set word wrap to 50 characters
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');      // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg'); // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                 // Set email format to HTML



//VARIABLES FROM FORM FIELDS
$contractor = $_POST['ct'];
$noactive = $_POST['noconactivity'];
$hours = $_POST['hours'];
$project = $_POST['prjx'];
$city = $_POST['cx'];
$street = $_POST['street'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$crewxtown = $_POST['cxtown'];
$construction = $_POST['construction'];
$mpt = $_POST['mpt'];
$direction = $_POST['direction'];
$police = $_POST['police'];
$optcomments = $_POST['optcomments'];
$submissionemail = $_POST['submissionemail'];
$mail_cm = $_POST['cm'];
$mail_pm = $_POST['pm'];
$intersection = $_POST['intersection'];
$parking = $_POST['parking'];


$count = count($street)-1;


$data = array();

//REPETITIVE VARIABLES
for( $i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++ )
{   
    $hours0 = $hours[$i];
    $street0 = $street[$i];
    $from0 = $from[$i];
    $to0 = $to[$i];
    $crewxtown0 = $crewxtown[$i];
    $construction0 = $construction[$i];
    $mpt0 = $mpt[$i];
    $direction0 = $direction[$i];
    $police0 = $police[$i];
    $optcomments0 = $optcomments[$i];
    $parking0 = $parking[$i];
    $intersection0 = $intersection[$i];

    $data[] = "$today, $noactive, $contractor, $hours0, $project, $city, $street0, $from0, $to0, $intersection0, $construction0, $mpt0, $crewxtown0, $direction0, $police0, $parking0, $optcomments0, $submissionemail, $mail_cm, $mail_pm\n";

$mail->Subject = $project;
$mail->Body    = 'Message content header stuff.<br><br><br><b>Street: </b> ' . $street0;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

}


// WRITING DATA TO CSV TABLE
if(!empty($data)) {
    $data = implode('', $data);

    $fh = fopen("dailyupdatedata.csv", "a");
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fclose($fh);
}


//SUCCESS & FAILURE MESSAGE ON PHP PAGE

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

**Here is the mail() code that works but does not consistently send.**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$contractor = $_POST['ct'];
$noactive = $_POST['noconactivity'];
$hours = $_POST['hours'];
$project = $_POST['prjx'];
$city = $_POST['cx'];
$street = $_POST['street'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$crewxtown = $_POST['cxtown'];
$construction = $_POST['construction'];
$mpt = $_POST['mpt'];
$direction = $_POST['direction'];
$police = $_POST['police'];
$optcomments = $_POST['optcomments'];
$submissionemail = $_POST['submissionemail'];
$mail_cm = $_POST['cm'];
$mail_pm = $_POST['pm'];
$intersection = $_POST['intersection'];
$parking = $_POST['parking'];
$count = count($street)-1;

$today = date("F j - Y - g:i a");//

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= "Please see the info blah blah<br><strong>Date:</strong> $today<br><strong>Submission by:</strong> $submissionemail<br><br>"; // Beginning message content
$data = array();

for( $i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++ )
{   
    $hours0 = $hours[$i];
    $street0 = $street[$i];
    $from0 = $from[$i];
    $to0 = $to[$i];
    $crewxtown0 = $crewxtown[$i];
    $construction0 = $construction[$i];
    $mpt0 = $mpt[$i];
    $direction0 = $direction[$i];
    $police0 = $police[$i];
    $optcomments0 = $optcomments[$i];
    $parking0 = $parking[$i];
    $intersection0 = $intersection[$i];

    $data[] = "$today, $noactive, $contractor, $hours0, $project, $city, $street0, $from0, $to0, $intersection0, $construction0, $mpt0, $crewxtown0, $direction0, $police0, $parking0, $optcomments0, $submissionemail, $mail_cm, $mail_pm\n";

    $message .= "<strong>Project:</strong> $project<br><strong>Active / Not Active:</strong> $noactive<br><strong>Contractor:</strong> $contractor<br><strong>Town:</strong> $city<br><strong>Hours:</strong> $hours0<br><strong>Street:</strong> $street0<br><strong>From:</strong> $from0<br><strong>To:</strong> $to0<br><strong>Intersection:</strong> $intersection0<br><strong>Construction Activity:</strong> $construction0<br><strong>MPT:</strong> $mpt0<br><strong>Crew Town:</strong> $crewxtown0<br><strong>Closure Direction:</strong> $direction0<br><strong>Police & Flaggers:</strong> $police0<br><strong>Parking Restrictions:</strong> $parking0<br><strong>Optional Comments:</strong> $optcomments0<br><br> -- <br><br>"; //Data for message
}
$message .= '</body></html>';

if(!empty($data)) {
    $data = implode('', $data);

    $fromemail = "email@email.com"; // email@email.com
    $subject = $project; 

    //$headers = "From:" . $fromemail;
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: "."Team Traffic "." <email@email.com>" . "\r\n";

    mail($submissionemail,$subject,$message,$headers); // Submission Email
    mail($mail_cm,$subject,$message,$headers); // C Manager Email
    mail($mail_pm,$subject,$message,$headers); // P Manager Email
    mail("email@email",$subject,$message,$headers);
    //mail($trafficemail,$subject,$message,$headers); // Traffic


    $fh = fopen("dailyupdatedata.csv", "a");
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fclose($fh);
}

?>
```

Am I missing a step here? Does PHPMailer not work with looping over variables?

Thank you,
Eric

Comment: you are overwritting `$mail->Subject`,`$mail->Body` and `$mail->AltBody` in each loop iteration. Simply append a string like you do in your older code, then set ->Body as that string

Comment: Thanks @ user574632. You are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$mail->Body    = 'Message content header stuff.<br><br><br><b>Street: </b> ' . $street0;
```

You are doing that in a loop, that means your code is overwriting the email body on every iteration and only the last one will stay. And then you exit the loop and send the email.

You should be appending those values to the body instead of overwriting the value.

```
$mail->Body.="New content for new project";
           ^
```

Comment: Yep. A single little . causing me so much confusion. Thanks so much for the input and help! I greatly appreciate it. Will mark as correct when time limit is up.

Answer (score 0):

I think `$mail->Subject = $project;` should be out of the loop.

As for body I think you forgot adding a dot(.=) to accumulate the message.

```
$mail->Body .= 'Message content header stuff.<br><br><br><b>Street: </b> ' . $street0;
```